# MySQL says "Table 'database.table' doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I connect my Rails app to MySQL database, working with that and after turning off the laptop and starting Rails and MySQL server again, I get the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Table 'database.table' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `table`):
```

This is in Rails log.

When I log in into MySQL through the terminal

```
mysql -u root -p
```

choose a database and then try to display data from a table, like

```
mysql> select * from users;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'database.users' doesn't exist
```

I google this issue and found a temporarily solution, but this is not appropriate because it involves remove all old data in the respective database:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/data
sudo rm -rf database_name
```

So I would like to ask you for help - how to properly figure out this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using rails, did you issue the command

```
rake db:migrate
```

And while you're in mysql I suggest you to get the list of available tables with:

```
show tables;
```